# Calling azure function from client app in browser on behalf authorized user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, session-cookies, azure-authentication

My goal is to have Angular 8 SPA with a serverless backend represented by multiple azure function apps using OAuth from Facebook, Google...

I have a problem with calling azure functions on behalf of authorized users. Function sees these calls as anonymous users.

**From the browser, function returns authorized user name, from browser app call it returns 'no name' that mean user is not authorized.**

My guess is that the session from *myapp.azurewebsites.net* is not visible in my app that is in the *localhost* (it can be any other domain). Also, I can't provide session in the request to function endpoint.

**So, what is the way to authorize users and call azure functions from the client app in other domain? Or it is possible only with the manual implementation of JWT tokens with spreaded logic across all functions?**
Also, I do not want to pay to third-party services like Auth0 or even AAD.

Jim Xu, suggested a way that works, but not for my case.
Disadvantages I see:

- With this approach, I can't see the user name and email in the
  claims principal. Also not sure what can I use as user Id.
- Login logic will be spread across all apps that are using the API.
- Will need to store FB token to authenticate all function apps

**I am looking for answers to such questions:**

1. Is there backend driven authentication for my case?
2. Is there an ability to setup post_login_redirect_url to receive a token for
   service also?
3. Maybe it is possible to set up via
   https://resources.azure.com/ ?
4. Is it possible to share access token for multiple
   function apps?
   (In this way, UI logic will be
   simplified to make get to app/.auth/login/provider and then save a
   service token.)

My code sample and configurations:

Here is a client app main parts I am using to call:

```
<button (click)="call('https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Function1')">CallWithoutAuth</button>
<button (click)="call('https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Function2')">CallWithAuth</button>

<a href="https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook?post_login_redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000" target="_blank">Log in with Facebook</a>
```

Body of call function:

```
var url = 'my azure func url with auth via facebook';
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.onerror = function(e){console.log(e, this)};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Function code:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
 [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "Func2")] HttpRequest req, 
 ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    var name = claimsPrincipal?.Identity?.Name;
    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name ?? "no name"}");
}
```

Here are functions app configs:

[image]

CORS config:

[image]

Fasebook config:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following steps to call the Azure function projected by facebook

1. Integrate Facebook into your angular application. after doing that, we can login facebook and get a `accessToken`. For more details about how to implement it, please refer to the [article](https://w3path.com/angular-8-social-login-with-example/").

   For example

   a. add the application URL into `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs`

   b. add the following code in `app.component.ts`

   ```
   export class AppComponent {
     title = 'web';
     fbLibrary() {

       (window as any).fbAsyncInit = function() {
         window['FB'].init({
           appId      : '<app id you use to project azure function>',
           cookie     : true,
           xfbml      : true,
           version    : 'v3.1'
         });
         window['FB'].AppEvents.logPageView();
       };

       (function(d, s, id){
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

   }
   ngOnInit() {
     this.fbLibrary();
   }
     login() {

       window['FB'].login((response) => {


           if (response.authResponse) {
            //get access token
             var accessToken=response.authResponse.accessToken;
             console.log('login response',accessToken);
             window['FB'].api('/me', {
               fields: 'last_name, first_name, email'
             }, (userInfo) => {

               console.log("user information");
               console.log(userInfo);
             });

           } else {
             console.log('User login failed');
           }
       }, {scope: 'email'});
   }
   }
   ```

   c. add login button to html
2. Call the following request to exchange this accessToken for an 'App Service Token'

Request

```
   POST https://<appname>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad HTTP/1.1
  Content-Type: application/json

  {"access_token":"<token>"}
```

Response

```
{
    "authenticationToken": "...",
    "user": {
        "userId": "sid:..."
    }
}
```

[image]

3. call the azure function

```
Get https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Function1
X-ZUMO-AUTH: <authenticationToken_value>
```

[image]
For further information, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to.

Comment: Thanks, It works, but not like I expected.
Issues:
1) With this approach, I can't see the user name and email in the claims principal. Also not sure what can I use as user Id.
2) Login logic will be spread across all users of the API.

Alternative?:
**Is there backend driven authentication for my case?**
Is there an ability to setup post_login_redirect_url to receive a token for service also?
Maybe it is possible to set up via https://resources.azure.com/ ?
(In this way, UI logic will be simplified to make get to app/.auth/login/provider and then save a service token.)

Comment: @VitaliyGoncharuk   As far as I knew, we have no way to do that. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#authentication-flow. Besides, regarding the user's information, you can send request to ```/.auth/me.``` to get

Comment: @VitaliyGoncharuk Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: @VitaliyGoncharuk Since you have no other concerns, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people.